# How do you set up a WMS data store (WMS cascade) in geoserver against a WMS that uses x509 authentication?

Tags: x509, geoserver

I'd like to add a WMS data store to my geoserver instance and have had success with WMS servers that have no authentication or basic username/password authentication, but I am now attempting to add a data store that uses x509 as its authentication method and I'm stumped.

When adding a WMS datastore through the admin console UI, all that's available is the username/password authentication:
[Connection Info Under for Creating a New WMS Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e86qq.png)

I have pored over the documentation and found the section detailing how to secure geoserver with x509 authentication, but haven't been able to turn up configuring geoserver as the x509 client.

I am familiar with and am using the properties for the ssl keystore and truststore but haven't been able to find anything indicating a client certificate store. I'm beginning to wonder if I need to setup a forward proxy that is configured with the proper client certs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is (currently) no support for more than basic authentication in the [GeoTools WMS datastore](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/extension/wms/index.html) that GeoServer uses for cascading. So you can either add a local proxy to handle the X509 authentication for GeoServer or extend the existing code to handle other authentication methods.